# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, lumen

I write a lumen code to update my table fields,
 this is my code -

```
$field='';
if($request->input('category')){
   $val=$request->input('category');
   $field="'category' => '$val'";
}
if($request->input('subcategory')){
   $val=$request->input('subcategory');
   if($field==''){
      $field="'sub_category' => '$val'";
   } else{
      $field.=",'sub_category' => '$val'";
   }
}
// return $field;

$Expence=DB::table('expencedetails')
           ->where('id',$request->input('id'))
           ->update(['$field']);
```

the value of `$field` is `'category' => 'fgfg'`, `'sub_category' => 'ggg'`.

when I run the code it shows an error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field
>   list' (SQL: update `expencedetails` set `0` = $field where `id` = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to rewrite your logic as

```
$fields=array();
if($request->input('category')){
    $fields['category'] = $request->input('category');
}
if($request->input('subcategory')){
    $fields['sub_category'] = $request->input('subcategory');
}
$Expence=DB::table('expencedetails')
           ->where('id',$request->input('id'))
           ->update($fields);
```

- If request has category then update category
- If request has only sub_category then update sub_category
- If request has both category
  and sub_category then update both

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid : no changes made

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `expencedetails` set `0` = fgfg, `1` = ccccc where `id` = 2)

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A My bad you need to pass key/value array to `update()` function check updated answer

Comment: Thank you its work...  and can you please check this question  [ https://stackoverflow.com/q/48072586/9143792 ]

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid : if i want to update the column 'sub_category' with empty value what i do ??

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A I guess $fields['sub_category'] = NULL should work

Answer (score 1):

Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#updates

> Syntax:
>
> ```
> ->update(['votes' => 1]);
> ```

I think your update has missing parameter

```
->update(['$field'])
```

Following change may help:

```
->update(['your_column_name_here' => $field])
```

Comment: $field contains 'your_column_name_here' => $value;  please read my code once more

Comment: Check khalid junaid's answer. it is valid